# How to scan room contour data from a floor plan using OpenCV or deep learning?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I want to find every room's accurate contour data such as bedrooms and living rooms, using OpenCV and Python, but can't do it well.maybe use CNN?

I tried to use `cv2.erode`, `cv2.dilate`, and `cv2.findContours`.

Here is an example of a floor plan to scan: 
[image]
I really expect result contains all the space of the special room, including furniture, but can not contain space in other rooms, such as the bedroom can not contain the space of the living room, and the outline can not contain curves. I except just like this:
[image]

Here is my python code:

```
import cv2
import random
img = cv2.imread('./lj_hx/zz.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)

mor_img = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, (5, 5), iterations=3)

_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mor_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

for c in sorted_contours[1:]:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 6000:
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(0, 256), random.randrange(0, 255)), 3)

cv2.imshow("mor_img", mor_img)
cv2.imshow("img", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Attach the image directly on the post, it's easier to read and also prevents issues with dead links in the future.

Comment: Post your code to show us what you’ve done/tried so far.

Comment: You will need to have a size threshold so that only the larger contours above a certain size are stored in your vector.

Comment: Edit your code into your question - and make sure it is correctly indented

Comment: @VictorAnuebunwa sorry, I'am newer and have not enough reputation

Comment: @Niels Henkens wish get you help,thanks

Comment: @Suleiman  size threshold is not enough, I can't get normative contour

Comment: @NielsHenkens thank you answer my question, I edit it again, I really cant solve it, wish you help

Comment: @NielsHenkens `except for 1 bedroom, where the bed is not included ` I just want to solve such problems, I really need is contour data, per room should include inner furniture

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the part that you "can't do [...] well"? I tried your code, plotted the areas in the center of the rooms and it looks pretty well (except for 1 bedroom, where the bed is not included). Is that what you meant, or didn't you get this far?

```
import cv2
import random
img = cv2.imread('./lj_hx/zz.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)

mor_img = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, (3, 3), iterations=3)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mor_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # I addapted this part of the code. This is how my version works (2.4.16), but it could be different for OpenCV 3 

sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

for c in sorted_contours[1:]:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 6000:
        print area
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(0, 255), random.randrange(0, 255)), 3)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c) # the lines below are for getting the approximate center of the rooms
        cx = x + w / 2
        cy = y + h / 2
        cv2.putText(img,str(area),(cx,cy), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5,(255,0,0),1,cv2.CV_AA)

cv2.imshow("mor_img", mor_img)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```